# Mips assembly language isolating bits

Tags: hex, decimal, mips

I have 16 hexadecimal values that I'm trying to loop through and isolate the bits at b6,b2,b1,b0 thats where i got the the 0x47 from.

```
.data
  #dellares all 16 test cases hexadecimal values
  testCases: .byte 0x0,0x1,0x2,0x3,0x4,0x5,0x6,0x7,0x40,0x41,0x42,0x43,0x44,0x45,0x46,0x47

  #set size of array to 16
  size: .word 16

  NL: .asciiz "\n"
  .text       

main:
lw $s7, size
move $s1, $zero
move $s2, $zero

loop:
bge $s1, $s7, loop_end  
lb  $s0, testCases($s2)

andi $a0, $s0, 0x47
li  $v0, 1
syscall
la $a0, NL

li       $v0, 4
syscall
addi     $s1, $s1, 1
addi     $s2, $s2, 4
j        loop

loop_end:
```

However this does not print out the desired result, it prints out [these results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MuMl.png)

Than you for any help

Answer (score 0):

You're going through an array of bytes, so you should just add 1 to `$s2`, not 4.

In case you were hoping to print the results in hexadecimal form, then you're going to have to write you own routine for converting the numbers to strings because SPIM doesn't have a system call for that. [MARS does](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/mars/Help/SyscallHelp.html), but it will add leading zeroes so that every number is printed with 8 hexadecimal digits.

Also, I didn't really find it clear if you just wanted to get those 4 bits, or if you also wanted to group them together (e.g. `0x43` -> `0xB`). If you want to group them together it's going to take a little more than just an AND (and additional AND, a right shift, and an OR, to be precise).